# how to use the value of an item in a mongoose schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to get the value of item in a schema and use it in the same schema.

**e.g Have a**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const TestSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    appellant: String,
    respondent: String,
    title: `${this.appellant} V. ${this.respondent}`,
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Test", TestSchema);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, a [virtual schema](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#virtuals) is used for instances such as this. It allows you to utilize the data in a particular format, without persisting it and creating redundant data.

In your case, it would look something like this:

```
TestSchema.virtual('title').get(function () {
   return this.appellant + ' V. ' + this.respondent
});
```

Comment: Virtuals do not save the values to the database

Comment: Correct, as I stated in my answer. Is there a reason you want data to be persisted twice?? Generally, this is bad practice. The data is stored already, you simply need access to it in a particular format. This is why virtuals are the correct solution here, as it avoids duplicate data storage.

Comment: Assuming i use virtuals, how do i get the value of the "title" ?